# Return Single Response using PHP_SELF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to run a function because of the way it's included and called within my plugin page I can't directly call the functions.php file, so what I'm trying to do now is work on the registration script, the problem is my returns can't be utlized the way I would like. For instance.

```
public function CheckUserName() {
            $query = <<<SQL
            SELECT id
            FROM {$this->tprefix}accounts
            WHERE username = :posteduser
SQL;
            $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':posteduser'   => $_POST['username'],
            ));
            if($resource->rowCount() == 0 ) {
                //Self Continue to run checks
                 }
                else {
                echo "1";
                }
        }
```

is my check to make sure that a username isn't already taken, whereas two will be my response echoed if the email is already in use. My Ajax is

```
$(function() {
  $("#register_").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();  
    var username = $("#username").val();
    if(username == "") { $("#unameerror").html("Username is Required"); }
    $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: $("#register_").attr("action"),
      data: $("#register_").serialize(),
      success: function(data) { 
      if(data==1) { alert("Username is taken. Please choose another!" };
      if(data==2) { alert("Email already registered. Please select lost password
      if you have forgotten your password" };
      if(data==0) { alert("Account Created!") }; //0 is returned after all checks passed and scripts executed
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("Something isn't right");
      }


     });
    });
});
```

My issue is since it's running from PHP_SELF it's putting out all information(IE `<html><title>reg script</title><body><form id = "reg"></form></body><html>`
The best way I can think to put this is how can I parse all my data return to simply return the script code?

Comment: How about this solution: send an extra field like 'action : xx'  in ajax data. Then use '$_POST['action']=='xx'' to check whether this page is called by the ajax, or by internet explorer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. =/ I'll tinker around with it, but right now I use process to tell it what form to send; I'm guessing there's something I don't know I could do to only return something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for my framework. Since everything is included into the index.php file and then just pulled through variables as includes it's always the index.php file
which is currently

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once(dirname(__file__).'/config.php');
require_once(dirname(__file__).'/directives.php');
LoadClasses();
$Theme->Load(ACTIVETHEME);
```

I simply changed the bottom part to

```
if(isset($_POST['process'])) {
}
else {
$Theme->Load(ACTIVETHEME);
}
```

Now it has no problem loading my pages, but when I execute a form with process input ( IE `<input type="hidden" name="process" id="process" value="register">` )
It now loads the page if no form is executed, but since I want all plugins to run through ajax it works great with that addition if a process was posted then it only returns the php scripts data.